# R truncates text files with certain encodings

Tags: r, text, character-encoding

I'm trying to read into R a test file encoded in Code page 437. [Here](http://adamobeng.com/downloads/437__characters.txt) is the file, and here is its hex-dump:

```
00000000: 0b0c 0e0f 1011 1213 1415 1617 1819 1a1b  ................
00000010: 1c1d 1e1f 2021 2223 2425 2627 2829 2a2b  .... !"#$%&'()*+
00000020: 2c2d 2e2f 3031 3233 3435 3637 3839 3a3b  ,-./0123456789:;
00000030: 3c3d 3e3f 4041 4243 4445 4647 4849 4a4b  <=>?@ABCDEFGHIJK
00000040: 4c4d 4e4f 5051 5253 5455 5657 5859 5a5b  LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[
00000050: 5c5d 5e5f 6061 6263 6465 6667 6869 6a6b  \]^_`abcdefghijk
00000060: 6c6d 6e6f 7071 7273 7475 7677 7879 7a7b  lmnopqrstuvwxyz{
00000070: 7c7d 7e7f ffad 9b9c 9da6 aeaa f8f1 fde6  |}~.............
00000080: faa7 afac aba8 8e8f 9280 90a5 999a e185  ................
00000090: a083 8486 9187 8a82 8889 8da1 8c8b a495  ................
000000a0: a293 94f6 97a3 9681 989f e2e9 e4e8 eae0  ................
000000b0: ebee e3e5 e7ed fc9e f9fb ecef f7f0 f3f2  ................
000000c0: a9f4 f5c4 b3da bfc0 d9c3 b4c2 c1c5 cdba  ................
000000d0: d5d6 c9b8 b7bb d4d3 c8be bdbc c6c7 ccb5  ................
000000e0: b6b9 d1d2 cbcf d0ca d8d7 cedf dcdb ddde  ................
000000f0: b0b1 b2fe 0a                             .....
```

The file contains 245 characters (including the final newline), but R only reads 242 of them:

```
> test_text <- readLines(file('437__characters.txt', encoding='437'))
Warning message:
In readLines(file("437__characters.txt",  :
  incomplete final line found on '437__characters.txt'
> test_text
[1] "\v\f\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\177 ¡¢£¥ª«¬°±²µ·º»¼½¿ÄÅÆÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôö÷ùúûüÿƒΓΘΣΦΩαδεπστφⁿ₧∙√∞∩≈≡≤≥⌐⌠⌡─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟╠╡╢╣╤╥╦╧╨╩╪╫╬▀▄█▌▐░▒"
> nchar(test_text)
[1] 242
```

You'll note that R doesn't read the final characters "▓■\n".

My best guess is that this is something to do with how R determines the length of text files, because of the following:

- Even though the file is terminated with a newline (`0x0a`), R gives an 'incomplete final line found' warning
- Adding seven or more characters to the end of the file makes it read correctly
- Similarly, the file is read correctly if you remove three characters from anywhere in the file
- The same issue seems to occur with reading files encoded in other DOS code pages

This question might be related: [R: read.table stops when meeting specific utf-16 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37270448/r-read-table-stops-when-meeting-specific-utf-16-characters).

Comment: Are you running R on Windows or Linux, and from which operating system does your file come?

Comment: I'm running OSX, and I created the file on OSX: 

R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens under R 2.15.1 on Linux, so I don't think it's platform-dependent.

Comment: When you suggested a problem at the end of the file I thought it might be the line endings.  I have upvoted your question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be something wrong with `readLines()`, but could very well be an issue with the `file` connection for text, with something amiss happening in the `encoding =` part.  Anyway, here's a **workaround**: Load the file as binary, and then convert.  And stay away from bad voodoo 1980s code pages.

#### Using `readLines()`

This does not capture the last `\n` since that delimits the unit of text input by `readLines().

```
test_text2 <- readLines(file("~/Downloads/437__characters.txt", raw = TRUE))
test_text3 <- stringi::stri_conv(test_text2, "IBM437", "UTF-8")

stringi::stri_length(test_text3)
## [1] 244

test_text3
## [1] "\v\f\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\034\033\177\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./
## 0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\032 ¡¢£¥ª«¬°±²μ·º
## »¼½¿ÄÅÆÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôö÷ùúûüÿƒΓΘΣΦΩαδεπστφⁿ₧∙√∞∩≈≡≤≥⌐⌠⌡─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟╠╡╢╣╤╥
## ╦╧╨╩╪╫╬▀▄█▌▐░▒▓■"
```

#### Using `readBin()`

Captures everything including the `\n`.

```
test_text_bin <- readBin(file("~/Downloads/437__characters.txt", "rb"), 
                         n = 245, what = "raw")
test_text_bin_UTF8 <- stringi::stri_conv(test_text_bin, "IBM437", "UTF-8")

stringi::stri_length(test_text_bin_UTF8)
## [1] 245

test_text_bin_UTF8
## [1] "\v\f\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\034\033\177\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./
## 0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\032 ¡¢£¥ª«¬°±²μ·º
## »¼½¿ÄÅÆÇÉÑÖÜßàáâäåæçèéêëìíîïñòóôö÷ùúûüÿƒΓΘΣΦΩαδεπστφⁿ₧∙√∞∩≈≡≤≥⌐⌠⌡─│┌┐└┘├┤┬┴┼═║╒╓╔╕╖╗╘╙╚╛╜╝╞╟╠╡╢╣╤╥
## ╦╧╨╩╪╫╬▀▄█▌▐░▒▓■\n"
```

Comment: I guess that's the most reasonable workaround, but I've emailed r-devel to see if it's a bug they're aware of.